# algorithm, algorithmic split code into parts with [H] remove line when no caption is set

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

I'm using `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` and want to split up the algorithm. Therefore I want the code parts to be at the position I'm explaining them, so I use the floating `[H]`. But the code starts with two lines when no caption is set (between `The calculation is done by` and `a+b\cdot c`) and I want to omit the first horizontal line there. A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
  Used input is
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{My Sum}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \Require $a,b,c$
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}

  The calculation is done by
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \State $a+b\cdot c$
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: Output of minimal working example]